# React- can't connect to server socket

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io

I build a server & client.
the client is trying to connect to the server by socket however I'm getting the following error in the console :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NS2s-Z_' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The server:

```
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');

const PORT =  process.env.PORT || 5000;


const router = require('./router');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

io.on('connection',(socket) =>{
    console.log('[Server] We have new connection !!!');
    socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
        console.log('[Server] WeUser has left !!!')
    });
});

app.use(router); 

server.listen(PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`[Server] has started listen on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

The client:

```
let socket;
const Chat= ({location}) =>{
    const ENDPOINT ='localhost:5000';
    const [name,setName] = useState('');
    const [room,setRoom] = useState('');
    useEffect(()=>{
        const {name,room} = queryString.parse(location.search) // get url
        socket = io(ENDPOINT);
        //Update state with new name and room
        setName(name);
        setRoom(room);
        console.log(socket);
        // socket.emit('ERROR');
    },[ENDPOINT,location.search]);
    return (<h1>Chat</h1>);
}
```

At first, I was sure the problem was that the server isn't on the same port as the client request. But sadly it's not the case.

Edit:
I've changed both ports to be 3000 and it seems to work, however, with any other port it's not. Is there a way the client cant send ack to connection because of os permission

Comment: Are you *sure* it's not due to the port numbers being different? [Different port numbers, if specified, mean different origins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), so, CORS.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, I've changed the server port to be 3000 and client ENDPOINT to be localhost:3000, and its works.
There is a way the problem related to OS?

Comment: Possible that requests to port 5000 are being blocked by your OS, yes. Check your firewall settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, you can try adding the transport on the client side, worked for me

```
const socket = io("localhost:5000", { transports: ["websocket"] });
```

Comment: Can you explain what the problem was?

Comment: unfortunately I don't really understand the problem, I had tried what was on the documentation and it didn't work so I found the solution [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/641) the way I described was the quickest way to test so I didn't look in to it much further

Answer (score 0):

Your express needs to enable CORS. Here is how. Install this package:

```
npm i cors
```

require it:

```
const cors = require('cors');
```

Then right below your `const app = express();`, paste this:

```
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: I've tried however I'm getting the same exception :
`polling-xhr.js:202 GET http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NS310zM net::ERR_FAILED`

______AND_____:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NS310zM' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

Comment: @GuyArilei What happens when you just pull up this url in the address bar of your browser? `http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NS310zM`

Comment: i think you should handle the cors like this

const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "https://example.com",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});

reference https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/